# how scroll length changes according to increase in the webpage length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Whenever the html page is of same dimension as the screen view scroll bar is not needed, as u go on  adding the elements in the webpage(refer my code) and length of the page is greater than the view scroll bar appears and changes according to the web length increases.I have already seen how to find the scroll position using scrolltop() etc .but never understood how it appears.

simple dummy code

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.box1{
height:50%;
width:100%;
border:1px solid black;
}
.box2{
height:50%;
width:100%;
border :1px solid black;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box1">
</div>
<div class="box2">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

page length increased

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.box1{
height:50%;
width:100%;
border:1px solid black;
}
.box2{
height:50%;
width:100%;
border :1px solid black;
}

 .box3{
height:50%;
width:100%;
border:1px solid black;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box1">
</div>
<div class="box2">
</div>
<div class="box3">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**`I am curious of how the browser calculates  scroll bar length(in %)  according to the length of the page and how the scroll bar length increases/decreases based on the webpage`** .
   Is there any mathematical formula (not sure)something like 
calculate the whole length of page (length of elements) - (view dimension of the browser)/(by some unknown variable).

Answer (score 0):

The browser takes the height of your screen (say 1000px), and calculates the percentage of the total document height. If the document height is 3000px, then the result is ~33%. Therefore the height of the scrollbar must be 33% of your screen height, which in pixels is 333px.

Answer (score 0):

It may be something like this

```
var heightIs = parseInt( $(window).height() / ( $("body").height() / $(window).height() ) );
```

You get the ratio bewteen body height and window height and then divide the window height with that ratio.